# TypeError: sequence item 1:expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, twitter

I want to download tweets from twitter as data sets for sentiment analysis using Python Twitter API ..

I am using SemEval 2016 task 6 dataset ..So I downloaded "[Domain corpus for task B](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task6/data/uploads/semeval2016-task6-domaincorpus.zip)" and I found a Readme file that describe the steps ..

I am just a beginner and I do not know much in python ..I installed python 3.4.3 and I already found easy_install.exe and pip.exe in scripts folder ..

I typed in cmd :  "easy_install twitter" as it is written in readme file ...then I tried to apply the steps from Readme file , here are the steps:

> The first time you run this, it should open up a web browser, have you log into
>
> Twitter, and show a PIN number for you to enter into a prompt generated by the
>
> script.
>
> 1. Login to Twitter with your user name in your *default* browser.
> 2. Run the script like this to download your credentials: `python download_tweets_api.py --dist=Donald_Trump.txt -- output=downloaded_Donald_Trump.txt`
> 3. Download tweets like so: `python download_tweets_api.py --dist=Donald_Trump.txt --output=downloaded_Donald_Trump.txt`

I finished step 1 , then I typed in cmd "download_tweets_api.py --dist=Donald_Trump.txt --output=downloaded_Donald_Trump.txt" but I got an error in last line of the file

**TypeError: sequence item 1:expected str instance, bytes found**

Here is the content of the file "download_tweets_api.py"

```
import sys
import os
import time
import datetime
import argparse
from twitter import *

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="downloads tweets")
parser.add_argument('--partial', dest='partial', default=None, type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('--dist', dest='dist', default=None, type=argparse.FileType('r'), required=True)
parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output', default=None,type=argparse.FileType('w'), required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()


CONSUMER_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

MY_TWITTER_CREDS = os.path.expanduser('~/.my_app_credentials')
if not os.path.exists(MY_TWITTER_CREDS):
oauth_dance("Semeval sentiment analysis", CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, MY_TWITTER_CREDS)
oauth_token, oauth_secret = read_token_file(MY_TWITTER_CREDS)
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(oauth_token, oauth_secret, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

cache = {}
if args.partial != None:
    for line in args.partial:
        fields = line.strip().split("\t")
        text = fields[-1]
        sid = fields[0]
        cache[sid] = text

for line in args.dist:
    fields = line.strip().split('\t')
    sid = fields[0]

    while not sid in cache:
        try:
            text = t.statuses.show(_id=sid)['text'].replace('\n', '  ').replace('\r', ' ')
            cache[sid] = text.encode('utf-8')
        except TwitterError as e:
            if e.e.code == 429:
                rate = t.application.rate_limit_status()
                reset = rate['resources']['statuses']['/statuses/show/:id'] ['reset']
                now = datetime.datetime.today()
                future = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(reset)
                seconds = (future-now).seconds+1
                if seconds < 10000:
                    sys.stderr.write("Rate limit exceeded, sleeping for %s  seconds until %s\n" % (seconds, future))
                    time.sleep(seconds)
            else:
                cache[sid] = 'Not Available'

    text = cache[sid]

    args.output.write("\t".join(fields + [text]) + '\n')
```

Note you can find the download_tweets_api.py and readme files in the "[domain corpus for task B](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task6/data/uploads/semeval2016-task6-domaincorpus.zip)"

Comment: here is a capture of the error from cmd : http://www.mediafire.com/view/0g5k3imjhmcyefc/errpython.JPG

Comment: here is the link to semeval datasets from which I got the link to mentioned corpus 
http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task6/index.php?id=data-and-tools

Comment: If you can, you might want to change your CONSUMER_KEY and secret.  In the future don't post those values on a public forum.  It is like writing your pin code on your bank card!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the last line of the `download_tweets_api.py` script. The script was written in Python 2 and would probably run seamlessly in Python 2. The main reason it is not running in Python 3 is that the last line is trying to `join` strings with bytes. However, in Python 3, `bytes` are *clearly* different from `strings`, in that you cannot join a byte to a string without coercing one into the other. In the case of this script, either the `text` variable or the `fields` variable (or even both) is of bytes elements. So, you may have to modify the variables `text` and `fields` before applying the string `join` function on them.

Basically, you will have to replace the last line of the script with the following:

```
#Create a function that converts the byte elements of the list fields into strings.
def convert(s):
  try:
    return str(s,encoding='utf8')
  except:
    return s
text = convert(text)
fields = list(map(lambda x: convert(x), fields))
args.output.write("\t".join(fields + [text]) + '\n')
```

If you do not want to modify the script, then you may have to run it in Python 2, or use the `2to3` module to convert the code to Python 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got an error in the line " text=str(text,encoding='utf8')"
 typeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: @Sarsoura the `text` is not a byte, so you do not need to decode it. I removed that line from the answer.

Comment: No..I got the same error in  the line of fields , here is the error from cmd
http://www.mediafire.com/view/m90makl1lyq8zcn/1err.JPG

Comment: @Sarsoura I just modified the answer. It seems that some elements of the `fields` list are not bytes; so that's causing the error. The function should take care of the conversion from byte to string.

Comment: Many thanks .. I tried the modified code but also it gave me this error in join function :
TypeError:sequence item 1 :expected str instance , bytes found
here is full error
http://www.mediafire.com/view/m90makl1lyq8zcn/1err.JPG

Comment: I added this line in your modified code : 
text =str(text) 
It did not give me errors:)  ...but I opened the output file and found some characters I think they are not converted like this  \xe2\x80\xa6'...
here is the output file 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/060y6gbzwcr9sp1/downloaded_Donald_Trump.txt

Comment: Please use `text = str(text, 'utf8')` not just `text = str(text)`. You really have to specify the encoding `utf8`. The reason you're getting bytes in your text file is because you did not decode the `text` variable.

Comment: I tried " text = str(text, 'utf8') " , I got the error "decoding str is not supported" ! also I tried text = str(text, encoding='utf8') I got the same error

Comment: I found here the code after fixing the bug to make it compatible with py 2 and 3 : https://github.com/aritter/twitter_download/blob/master/download_tweets.py
So I modified my  file , here it is the last version
http://www.mediafire.com/download/frft5jpd95mw94u/download_tweets_api.py
it worked with me :) here is the output file
http://www.mediafire.com/download/8raj2a2m7jg89cz/downloaded_Donald_Trump%283%29.txt

Comment: when I make Ctrl+C in cmd I got this output on cmd ... I think this is just traceback output .. I think no errors or corruption 
http://www.mediafire.com/view/v68d4a74rotxjo3/outfinal.JPG

Comment: @Sarsoura yea that should be just a traceback. As long as you're getting your text file with the tweets, you should be fine.